# Running JS AFTER Modal is open

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have tried many methods, such as:

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
 $('body.modal-open').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
        if ($("a.address").length) {
        var signupText = (hightestCount);
        $(".rg-modal-signup h2").text('Keep searching ' + signupText + ' real estate.');
    } else {
        var signupText = '';
         $(".rg-modal-signup h2").text('Keep searching for your dream home.');
    }
  }); });
```

and:

```
$('body.modal-open').on('shown', function(){
if ($("a.address").length) {
        var signupText = (hightestCount);
        $(".rg-modal-signup h2").text('Keep searching ' + signupText + ' real estate.');
    } else {
        var signupText = '';
         $(".rg-modal-signup h2").text('Keep searching for your dream home.');
    } });
```

Just not working, I can only seem to make it run code if a button prompts a modal, but not when the modal shows in different ways. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Give your modal an id and try using JQuery's :visible method.

```
if($('#modal').is(":visible")){

    if ($("a.address").length) {
        var signupText = (hightestCount);
        $(".rg-modal-signup h2").text('Keep searching ' + signupText + ' real estate.');
        } else {
        var signupText = '';
        $(".rg-modal-signup h2").text('Keep searching for your dream home.');
     }

}
```

If you insist on using boostrap's method

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
    $('body').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
        if ($("a.address").length) {
        var signupText = (hightestCount);
        $(".rg-modal-signup h2").text('Keep searching ' + signupText + ' real estate.');
} else {
    var signupText = '';
     $(".rg-modal-signup h2").text('Keep searching for your dream home.');
}
}); });
```

Comment: This doesn't work. The modal already has an id once DOM is loaded. That is why I used body.modal-open because that is triggered once modal is open.

Comment: $('body.modal-open') this jquery referencing is where you are getting an error. Find another way to grab the modal. let me update my answer to show you how you can do it if you insist on using your method.

Comment: Still not working. See this link and try to favorite a listing. The code won't trigger. [link](https://www.bothellhomes.com/search/results/?city=Bothell&area_min=all&list_price_min=50000&list_price_max=all&beds_min=all&baths_min=all&type=res&type=con#)

Comment: I just set this code to test if it will even work. The h2 should be replaced but it's not: $(".rg-modal-signup h2").text('Keep searching for your dream home.');

Comment: Try to quickly recreate the problem on a JSFiddle, send the link and we look at it.